# Image detail page in drupal

Tags: views

I am new to Drupal.I want to create an image gallery, where each Image have some details.

I have used [Media](https://www.drupal.org/project/media) and [File Entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_entity) modules to add additional field to media.

I want to know that how can I create a view to get details of that image.
Also how can I edit the details of that image